# Summation with given parameter :

Tags: real-analysis, summation, logarithms, closed-form

Consider the following sum:

$$F(x)=\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n\ln(n))^x}$$

Now this series converges for $x>1$.

Can we get a closed form of this function for $x>1$?